# How do I set a form's focus so that no control has the focus in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

Using C++ Builder XE6 and FireMonkey, how do I set a form's focus so no control has the focus?

I know that I can call SetFocus () on a control, but I don't want any specific control to have the focus.

Comment: This seems like a rather user-hostile goal. Why would want such a thing?

Comment: Any dialog which has buttons or edit controls, or in any way accepts keyboard input should automatically focus to a sensible default location.

Comment: It's a game, so the UI issues are a little different from a conventional app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi you can set the form's [`Focused`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.Focused) property to `nil`, e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Focused := nil;
end;
```

In C++ Builder it could be:

```c
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  Focused = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use Delphi 10.3.3 and Focused := nil; doesn't work.
at least it doesn't for work for me.

but, FocusControl(Nil); does work, and i think it's best to add it in the OnActivate Event of the Form.

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FocusControl(Nil);
end;
```